# Google Fit API, getting calories burned per activity

Tags: java, android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

So I'm trying to create an app that connects to Google Fit and shows the user their data in a pretty streamlined way and I'm having trouble finding the calories the user burned for each individual activity per day. I can get the total calories for the entire day, and each activity the user did each day, but not the calories burned for each activity.

Link to GitHub: https://github.com/drb56/FitTest
I've only added the java code not any of the xml stuff. And the Google Fit code is in the FitTestFragment.java. 
I'll paste some key code down below:

Here's where I connect to the google fit API client:

```
mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getContext())
            .addApi(Fitness.HISTORY_API)
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ))
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .enableAutoManage(getActivity(), 0, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
                Log.i("MyApp", "Google Play services connection failed. Cause: " +
                        result.toString());
        }})
        .build();
```

Here's where I make the DataReadRequest for specific information:

```
DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
                         .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_CALORIES_EXPENDED,     DataType.AGGREGATE_CALORIES_EXPENDED)
                        .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT, DataType.AGGREGATE_ACTIVITY_SUMMARY)
                        .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
                        .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                        .build();

    DataReadResult dataReadResult = Fitness.HistoryApi.readData(mClient, readRequest).await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);


    if (dataReadResult.getBuckets().size() > 0)
    {
        Log.i("MyApp", "Number of returned buckets of DataSets is: "
                + dataReadResult.getBuckets().size());
        for (Bucket bucket : dataReadResult.getBuckets())
        {
            List<DataSet> dataSets = bucket.getDataSets();
                     for (DataSet dataSet : dataSets)
                    {
                        dumpDataSet(dataSet);
                    }
                }
             }
            else
            {
                Log.i("MyApp", "No data");
            }
```

Here's what my output looks like for some activities and calories expended:

```
Data point:
    Type: com.google.calories.expended
    Date: 06/09/2016
    Start: 2:58:13 PM
    End: 2:58:13 PM
    Field: calories Value: 2555.9749
Data point:
    Type: com.google.activity.summary
    Date: 06/09/2016
    Start: 2:58:13 PM
    End: 2:58:13 PM
    Field: activity Value: 3
    Field: duration Value: 76513626
    Field: num_segments Value: 17
Data point:
    Type: com.google.activity.summary
    Date: 06/09/2016
    Start: 4:13:58 PM
    End: 12:41:04 PM
    Field: activity Value: 7
    Field: duration Value: 4553146
    Field: num_segments Value: 17
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get calories for various activities for each day by using the following code

```
DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
            .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_CALORIES_EXPENDED, DataType.AGGREGATE_CALORIES_EXPENDED)
            .bucketByActivityType(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .build();
```

You can run this code in a loop to get data for as many days as you want. It will return data buckets for all activities and you can fetch activity name from the bucket by this method that returns activity name as String

```
bucket.getActivity();
```

Store it in a custom Collection and you are good to go. Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to work with Fitness.SESSIONS_API, instead of Fitness.HISTORY_API. [Sessions](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/using-sessions) represent a time interval during which users perform a fitness activity.